# Printing a variable's content using lldb

Tags: c, debugging, lldb

Okay, so this is going to sound like a silly question, yet I am stuck : I have trouble reading the value of a variable during a lldb debugging session (things work fine with gdb).

I have found posts from other people who had encountered the same error message than myself, but the difference is that I can't even figure out how to print out the value of the simplest form of variable.

To better express my problem, I will consider a very simple example here. We have a file "main.c" containing the following code :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
  int c = 0;
  c = a + b;
  c = c*b;
  printf("c = %d\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it using :

```
user@machine ~ $ gcc -g main.c
```

A binary file named
    "a.out"
is generated

I then ivoque lldb :

```
user@machine ~ $ lldb-3.4 ./a.out
```

I want to stop at line 9 and read the value of c. Therefore, I start by adding a breakpoint :

```
(lldb) breakpoint set -f main.c -l 9
```

Then I run the code :

```
(lldb) run
```

Up until now, every thing goes as expected. Now comes the tricky part : I want to read the value of variable c. Therefore, I write :

```
(lldb) print c
```

And lldb returns me :

```
error: use of undeclared identifier 'c'
error: 1 errors parsing expression
```

Of course :

```
(lldb) expression c
```

returns exactly the same error message.

Is there anything that I missed ? Any help would be very much appreciated.

My setup :

- lldb : "lldb version 3.4 ( revision )" (package v. : "3.4~svn183914-1ubuntu1")
- gcc : "gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1" (package v. : "4.8.1-2ubuntu3")
- (my repositories are the ones provided by linux mint 16 by default)

---

Some more information following answer from @Sean Perry :

1: It seems that appending option -O0 does not change the debugger's behaviour.

2: I also tried to use the following dummy code instead of my previous one

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  long a = 1;
  long b = 2;
  long c = 0;
  c = a + b;
  c += (long) &c;
  printf("c = %ld\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

I am not certain that is what @Sean Perry meant by "using pointers", but I suppose it must prevent code optimisation anyway since the address of variable c (more or less) randomly changes for each run of the binary file.

3: Eventually, I noticed something interesting :

- compiling with gcc [-g -O0]  then debugging with gdb  : works
- compiling with gcc [-g -O0]  then debugging with lldb : does not work
- compiling with clang [-g -O0] then debugging with gdb  : works
- compiling with clang [-g -O0] then debugging with lldb : works

edit1 : reply to @SeanPerry
edit2 : distinguishing the software version from the package version

Comment: I've tried copy-pasting your exact code and compiled it both with `Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1` and `Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-12ubuntu1` and tried debugging it with lldb-3.4 ([stable branch](http://llvm.org/apt/)) and it worked (i.e `(lldb) print c` led to `(int) $0 = 3`)

Comment: @Scis : Awkward... are you on a 32 or a 64-bit machine ? (just wondering if there could be a glitch in the 64-b version of gcc that I am using). My gcc version is Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9, my lldb version is "lldb version 3.4 ( revision )".

I am a bit confused to whether this is a stable or an unstable build... On one hand, the lldb package in my repo is marked as "svn", on the other hand I installed it typing "aptitude install lldb-3.4", which is exactly the instructions given on [link] (http://llvm.org/apt/) the page you suggested me to read. Do you know how I could find this out ?

Comment: I'm using a 64-bit ubuntu 14.04 LTS. As for installation, seems like both of us installed it the same way (by the way did you install `clang-3.4` as advised as well? Try running `apt-get install clang-3.4 lldb-3.4` again maybe there's some version mismatch - this of course is just a speculation but again this is an odd behavior)

Comment: It seemed I had installed a `clang-3.2.*` version of `clang`. I also have `libllvm-3.3` and `libllvm-3.3:i386` installed along with `libllvm-3.4` (the 3.3 versions of the lib are dependencies of other software including `x.org` it seems). However, installing only `clang-3.4` and `lldb-3.4` does not seem to make any difference. Once again, the `clang`+`lldb` combo works fine, it's the `gcc`+`lldb` combo that fails. When I first posted my question, I thought I was not able of using lldb properly, but the more it goes, the more I feel the issue comes from a glitch in my particular `gcc` ver. ...

Comment: @Scis Indeed, the issue comes from my particular version of gcc (4.8.1). Using gcc 4.7.3 instead works fine. I assume that must have been a glitch that was corrected between my r. 4.8.1 and the r. 4.8.2 you have... So much for so little... (^.^') Thanks for the help !

Comment: I use `-O0 -g -DDEBUG=2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this was a specific issue when using `gcc 4.8.1` and `lldb-3.4`

Using `gcc-4.8.2` and `gcc-4.7.3` works fine.

Comment: Damn, you were quicker than myself for posting the answer ! (^.-)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to investigate the behavior you're seeing is to look at the debug info.  On a Mac OS X system, you'd run dwarfdump on the `.dSYM` bundle or on the `.o` file if you didn't create a dSYM.  The debug information has the instructions from the compiler to the debugger about where to find variables.

In a live process, with lldb, you can have lldb show you where all the local variables are stored (expressed in the DWARF location expression language) with `image lookup -v -a $pc` (or `im loo -va $pc` for short).

If there's a program where gdb can't print a variable and lldb *at the same pc address* cannot, that sounds like it could be an lldb bug.  The debug information is the ultimate truth (as far as the debugger is concerned) about where variables are stored and how long they are "live".  In optimized code, they may be live for very short sections of your function.

From a hack point of view, the real source of truth is to read the assembly code.  Often, under optimization, the compiler doesn't track the location of the variables as well as it could -- it may *say* that a variable is unavailable at a given pc address, but if you read the assembly closely enough, you might find a copy of the last value still saved on the stack & such.

Comment: Thanks for the information ! I am obviously quite new to all this and hence I never really looked into binary code with so much depth, so what you are saying is interesting to me. I looked up to see what `$pc` was (which I kind-of found), but then I wondered : is there other "special" variables that could be relevant for `lldb`-debugging ?

Comment: Other question : though the DWARF format is a standard debugging format, is the generation of *.dSYM files a widespread practice or is it mostly Mac-related ? Why do you seem to prefer separating the debugging information from the compiled code itself ? Strangely, I could not find the `gcc` or `clang` or option to generate those `*.dSYM` files, but I might have overlooked it...

Answer (score 0):

This code is so simple I bet llvm has removed the variables completely. Try compiling with optimizations disabled (-O0) and see if it helps. Beyond that, use a pointer or do something a little more complicated so the compiler does not removed your math and replace it with precomputed values.

Comment: An easy way to test this would be perhaps to use `objdump` on the binary and see what code it generates. Still, if it works with `gdb`..

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! I tried a few things following your answer, but unfortunately I was not very successful... I completed my original question with the results of today's tries.

Comment: @cnicutar I disassembled the binary using objdump, and it seems there is an addition and a multiplication going on in the binary file :

000000000040052d <main>:
[...]
  400551: 48 8b 55 e8           mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rdx
  400555: 48 01 d0              add    %rdx,%rax
  400558: 48 89 45 f8           mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
[...]
  40055c: 48 8b 45 f8           mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
  400560: 48 0f af 45 f0        imul   -0x10(%rbp),%rax
  400565: 48 89 45 f8           mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
[...]

This not a "hard" proof, but I suppose that means there must be a c variable somewhere.